# On login, subscription to the publish of all users need browser refresh

Tags: meteor

I've got a publication of all users reserved to `admin role`

```
//Publish all users just for admins
Meteor.publish ('allUsers', function(){
    if(Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')){
        return Meteor.users.find ({});
    }
});
```

Anywhere I put on the client this subscription,

```
//Subscribe to all users
Template.UsersAdmin.onCreated(function (){
    this.autorun (() => {
        this.subscribe('allUsers');
    });
});
```

when I login as `admin`, on the first load, I've got just a part of the user collection : for example, in `emails`, just the `address`, not the `verified field` (which I need to force users to verify their emails before anything).

When I reload the page, I've got everything. Other roles don't have this issue. Any idea what's going on ?

**EDIT - ANSWER**

The issue was not on this publish, but another one : `Meteor.users.find` had no `"emails.verified"` in `fields`...

```
Meteor.publish( 'contact-messages', function() {
  let isAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole( this.userId, 'admin' );

  if ( isAdmin ) {
    return [
      Meteor.users.find( {}, { fields: { "emails.address": 1, "emails.verified": 1, "roles": 1 } } ),
      //Invitations.find( {}, { fields: { "email": 1, "role": 1, "date": 1 } } )
      ContactMessages.find({},{})
    ];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Comment: i did a quick test and i could not reproduce what you're describing. i used meteortoys:allthings to confirm the verified field showed up in the client. in my test, user 'foo' was the admin, and non-admin user 'baz' had the email field. i saw it published when foo first logged in, and also upon page reload. no difference.

Comment: @zim You're right, the issue was on another publish (check my edited question). Sorry for my inattention and your time...